# Sort object of objects to obtain the sorted result in object format only

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this :

```
{
    "25276234": {
        "id": "25276234",
        "title": "new",
    },
    "4c57f8b9": {
        "id": "4c57f8b9",
        "title": "aa",
        },
    "c5353527": {
        "id": "c5353527",
        "title": "1",
        },
    "76517feb": {
        "id": "76517feb",
        "title": "bs",
        },
    "b6458d0c": {
        "id": "b6458d0c",
        "title": "new doc",
        },
    "d8ca47f7": {
        "id": "d8ca47f7",
        "title": "AAAA",
        },
    "2a72cba8": {
        "id": "2a72cba8",
        "title": "abcd",
        },
    "73694f31": {
        "id": "73694f31",
        "title": "A",
        }
}
```

My aim is to sort it based on the title and the final sorted result should be an object of this format only and not an array.

I have tried several ways like -

```
const sorted = {};
Object
    .keys(data).sort((o1,o2) => {
        return data[o1].title - data[o2].title;
    })
    .forEach((key) => {
        sorted[key] = data[key];
    });
```

But it is not being sorted for some reason.
What am I doing wrong and what is the solution?

Comment: See [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](/q/5525795/4642212). Objects are not intended to be used as ordered collections. Consider using [`Map`s](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead.

Comment: Can you change the structure something like this - ```[{id: "87f65ea4", title:"A"},{id: "87f6523f", title:"B"},{id: "6543awe23", title:"C"}]``` ?

Comment: Cant use map need an object only. Is there any solution?

Comment: @AnveegSinha No need the same format only since this is being used in react and being passed as props so need the same format only

Comment: `data[o1].title - data[o2].title` <- this is how you sort numbers or booleans. For strings, it should be `data[o1].title.localeCompare(data[o2].title)`. (FYI, even then `25276234` will always be enumerated first because it is an integer key)

Comment: @adiga it looks like `25276234` is an `id` field, not a `title` field.  The `id` fields all appear to be hex, so they could be sorted using the first method if the values are converted from hex strings to integers first.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety `25276234` is one of the keys of the object. Integer key will always be enumerated no matter the order of insertion.  So, `sorted` object will always enumerate `25276234` first because it is an integer: https://jsfiddle.net/d4mfkaxq/